# To run Python inside HTML -file similarly as PHP

Tags: python, frontend

I know that you can have PHP -code inside HTML -file.
I would like to know how you can do the same with Python.

**How can you run Python inside a HTML document?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at django templating engine for example. [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: I need to make my SQL queries by myself. I am afraid that I am not allowed to use Django.

Comment: You can still write your own queries with Django... Although I'll admit that defeats the purpose of using it.

Answer (score 6):

**[Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/index.html)**

> Cheetah is a Python-powered template engine and code generator. It may be used as a standalone utility or combined with other tools. Cheetah has many potential uses, but web developers looking for a viable alternative to ASP, JSP, PHP and PSP are expected to be its principle user group.

Comment: @Charles: Cheetah sounds promising. I need to create my SQL queries by myself. Does Cheetah allow me to create my own SQL queries?

Answer (score 3):

You will need something like mod_python for apache, or play with cgi.

It really depends on your web server

Comment: There are HTTP servers that are written in plain python. AFAIR python standard library includes one. There's no need to run apache for smale-scale deployments.

Comment: That's why I said it really depends on the web server :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/). Both are very fast, and best at doing their job. You should not create SQL queries in your template, but in your controller logic. Later, pass variables/functions to a template and output them.